# Prevent from onClick on multiple (submit) buttons when form data are invalid (vee-validate)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, validation, submit

How can I prevent from calling onClick event **on button** if some input is not valid (using vee-validate ValidationObserver). I need this on button not on the form because I have multiple buttons (calling different methods or using different parameters) that should be executed only if data are valid.

Snippet for better understanding:

```
<validation-observer ref="myValidator">
  <form>
    <validation-provider rules="required" v-slot="{ errors }">
      <input type=”text”>
    </validation-provider>
    <validation-provider rules="required" v-slot="{ errors }">
      <input type=”text”>
    </validation-provider>
    <button onClick=”if inputs are valid call method1”>
    <button onClick=”if inputs are valid call method2”>
  </form>
</validation-observer>
```

Is there “built-in” or better solution than testing an ValidationObserver in code (like `this.$refs.resCodesValidator.validate()`) inside onClick methods?

Answer (score -1):

Yes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation

```
<form>
  <label for="fname"> name (required)</label>
  <input id="fname" name="fname" required>
  <label for="choose">Would you prefer a banana or a cherry?</label>
  <input id="choose" name="i_like" required pattern="[Bb]anana|[Cc]herry">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```